Ramak's Pardes Rimonim English translation
I'm looking to see if anyone has translated the Pardes Rimonim of Moshe Cordovero into English.
I found a record online of a translation by Elyakim Getz, but I can't find any information about who he is or whether he ever finished or intends to finish his translation. His translation is listed on the National Library of Israel as covering parts 1-12 over 4 volumes, but the last volume listed was published in 2010:
https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990034995750205171/NLI
Does anyone know about what's going with this translation, or know of any other translations?

With just a little research, this purported translator is affiliated with the Universal Life Church in Monfalcone, Italy under an offshoot called Providence University. That church is connected with mail-order marriage ministries and tax fraud in Italy, Canada and the United States.

I haven't seen the translation of Elyakim Getz itself, but the publisher indeed does not give much confidencence that (one can buy or obtain for free any degree of one's choice from Providence "University"). People who have seen the translation say it is (more or less) based on Google Translate. I do not know of any other translation in English.
The whole of the Pardes is read, translated and interpreted in French by Michael Sebban of Beit haZohar in Paris, in an impressive series of videos.
https://www.youtube.com/@zohar1/playlists
It took him more than 10 years to complete (September 2024).

There is also a masterful French translation available by the somewhat mysterious "Rafael Ben Avraham" https://www.lulu.com/fr/shop/rafael-ben-avraham/sefer-pardes-rimonim-livre-du-jardin-de-grenades-i/paperback/product-18732742.html?srsltid=AfmBOopQpqO5Ij4EhCWANJ6IxkSiPTFYaHKt3WZz1dMUU6D_GbCJKAIR&page=1&pageSize=4

The majority of speakers on the Beit HaZohar's website do not have Jewish last names or cover their heads and the woman speaker does not cover her hair. Thanks for sharing, @Stephan!

@יהושעק many of the names I see are traditional Jewish surnames (I see a mix of both Ashkenazi and Sepharadi names)... as for head covering, many traditional women do not cover their hair today (see responsum of R. Yosef Messas on this). If your point is that one ought investigate an organization before blindly consuming its content, that's certainly true... but I wouldn't say that your points are relevant to such an assessment.

@Deuteronomy many of the men do not wear head coverings either

@יהושעק may traditional Sepharadim regularly go about without a head-covering. Many of my Syrian friends growing up always kept a kippah in their pocket and would put it on for meals (when blessings are recited) and for minyan. My impression is that in Europe this is also more common. Again, not dispositive of anything...

@Deuteronomy this is common practice in Israel as well. But when you're taking headshots for a Torah insitution, particularly one that teaches Zohar...

@יהושעק there are many who hold there is no halakhah for men to wear a headcovering, and there is indeed a long history of rabbinic portraiture without it (see Yarmulke: A Historic Coverup?)... there are more fitting ways of looking into an organization

@יהושעק, could you please clarify on which your opinion of "Rafael Ben Avraham"'s French translation as "masterful" is based? I find him missing a Gematria already on the second page of his translation. That there is no information to find on the name or background of the translator does not help. But I might be misinformed. Thanks for any help!
